# unlist without creating decimals

Tags: r

I did not find a dupe, although this certainly must have been asked before :/

How do I `unlist` a list (or even a vector) of numerics without creating decimals in those elements that do not have decimals in the first place (pun semi-intended).

```r
unlist(list(1, 1.11))
#> [1] 1.00 1.11
```

Comment: convert to character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we convert to character, it would remain as such.  Otherwise, the `print` should be changed

```
unlist(lapply(list(1, 1.11), as.character))
#[1] "1"    "1.11"
```

Comment: @Tjebo just curious, why do you need in such a format

Comment: Put simply, just to make it look pretty :) For a convenience function showing simple summary stats. The sample number 'n' should not show decimals, because it can't be only part observations.

Answer (score 5):

`formatC`/`prettyNum` would also work for this:

```
formatC(unlist(list(1, 1.11)))
## [1] "1"    "1.11"

prettyNum(unlist(list(1, 1.11)))
## [1] "1"    "1.11"
```

Actually, `as.character` seems to be sufficient:

```
as.character(list(1, 1.11))
## [1] "1"    "1.11"
```

Though that works as you expect it only if the `list` elements are single values:

```
as.character(list(1, 1.11, c(2, 2.22), list(3, 3.33)))
## [1] "1"             "1.11"          "c(2, 2.22)"    "list(3, 3.33)"
```

From the help file for `as.character`:

> For lists and pairlists (including language objects such as calls) it deparses the elements individually, except that it extracts the first element of length-one character vectors.

In those cases, using `as.character` *after* `unlist` would make more sense:

```
as.character(unlist(list(1, 1.11, c(2, 2.22), list(3, 3.33))))
## [1] "1"    "1.11" "2"    "2.22" "3"    "3.33"
```